# Fastest and easiest way to explode and find a string between a delimiter

Tags: php

i want to check if there is a match in this string with a string I'm looking for.

```
$string='my|string|between|delimiters';
also
$string='my|string';
also
$string='my';
```

normally I will do it in this way

```
$check=explode('|',$string);
if (in_array("string", $check)) {
   echo 'goal';
}
```

Now I ask myself if there is a better, easier, faster way to to the same job?

Comment: Do a character by character comparison. When you say faster and easier, you are entering into the algorithm arena and yes there is a faster way for string comparison but then you are too much complicating your task where your simple in_array check was enough.

Comment: If you are searching for a faster approach, can you prove a case where the current approach is taking too much time?

Comment: explode() is faster though.

Comment: 1) If it works: great.  There's certainly nothing "wrong" with your solution.  2) Maybe [if (strpos($check) < 0)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) might be suitable.  3) If not, a [regex](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_regex.asp)  would also be worth considering.

Comment: $liststring= array(my, string, between, delimiters); 
  
if (in_array("string", $liststring)) 
  { 
  echo "goal"; 
  }